# Form submit using partail View error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-ajax

I have created a form for add comment. I have created it in main View called Index in Home controller. bellow is Index View

```
private projectDBEntities db = new projectDBEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult AddComment()
    {
        return PartialView("_Comment");
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddComment(comment cmt)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.comments.Add(cmt);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return PartialView("_Comment", cmt);
    }
```

below is _Comment Partial View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {@Html.AntiForgeryToken()@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>comment</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cmd_content)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cmd_content)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cmd_content)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.t_email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.t_email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.t_email)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Comment" />
    </p>
</fieldset>}
```

System.Web.HttpException was occuerd. I want to know What is the reason behind this error and what is the best method to form submit using partail View.

Comment: describe your exception

Comment: you cant use a form like that, you will have duplicate fields if you add it more than once. Also it will all map to the same fields on the Model. Are you using a unique Model for each partial view created? You need to make all field IDs unique and Model mappings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id have to agree with Sandip's answer here, but to elaborate ..

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "Home")) 
{
        //Content to send to the server-side
}
```

As long as your model in your partial view points to your 'Comment' object, then this should work fine when using `@Html.EditorFor()`.  In your controller, your already waiting for your 'Comment' object to be populated.  So on Post, when the submit is clicked, it will populate that object.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "Home"))
{

}

Comment: Try to use Ajax.BeginForm(). It will give performance to your website.